# A simple solution I could apply to join/concatenate 3 lines of text together using Vim

Tags: vim

I was looking for a simple solution I could apply to join/concatenate 3 lines of text together using Vim. I wanted to take a file containing 36 short strings and join every 3 lines, in effect producing just 12 longer lines. (For anyone reading this and wondering why - I was producing a markdown table around some shortcut commands).
So the example is, I had wanted to take:

```
1 short-line one  
2 short-line two  
3 short-line three
```

and have:

```
1 short-line one 2 short-line two 3 short-line three
```

across the file.

Comment: Write a macro if they are always three lines separated by a empty line or something look at `:h macro` but basically something like Go to first line of the three to join then `qq` to start recording. Type in `:.,+3j!` then `q`. Move to top of next block to join and type `@q` . If you set `:set nowrapscan` then `n@q` will run the macro n times

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution I discovered was:

```
:%norm 3gJ
```

% is execute the following command from line 1 to the end. The norm command runs the normal mode commands equivalent to the letters that follow it. g and capital J is the shortcut for join and finally, the 3 is for three 3 lines.

I hope that this might be useful to someone else searching for a simple solution in the future.

Comment: Your description is incorrect: the `g` in `gJ` is not a separate command. See `:help gJ`.

Comment: It's a very interesting answer! But your explanation is incorrect, as romainl pointed out. Also, you might actually want `:%norm 3J` instead, since that will add a space between the lines you joined. (That would match your example from the question.)

Comment: Hi romaini, thanks for dropping by. As I understand it each element (combined) makes up the overall command?

Comment: `gJ` is a whole command by itself. See [`:help gJ`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#gJ). It seems you're mixing it up with the `:g` command (see `:help :g` for that.) In any case, I think `J` might be slightly better than `gJ` for your specific case, since it adds spaces between the joined lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by putting the cursor on the first line of the three to be joined.

Then type `:` followed by `.,+2j!`

`.` - Current line

`+2` - To 3rd line from current

`j!` - Join the lines with adding spaces

`j` - joins adding spaces in between.

Transforms

```
1 short-line one  
2 short-line two  
3 short-line three
```

to

```
1 short-line one  2 short-line two  3 short-line three
```

Or record a macro
`qq` - Start recording (replace second q with any alphabetic character

Poistion cursor on first line to join and Type

```
`:.,+2j!`
```

Type `q` to stop recording

Then move to first lline of next block say on `4 short-line-one` of the below

```
4 short-line one
5 short-line two
6 short-line three
```

Type `@q` to repeat macro.

You can make it repeatable but that's more than I have time for today